# (Python) TypeError: Required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I've seen many questions like this but people have always given the solution and not what was wrong.

I have this piece of code and it gives me the error: "TypeError: Required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found", and I don't know what the error is.

```
from os import *
from time import *

var_1 = open("{}/Dekstop/Test_file.txt".format(environ["USERPROFILE"],"a"))
var_2 = "Test"

if var_1.find(var_2):
   print("yay")
else:
   print("noo")
sleep(5)
```

I would appreciate help.

Comment: You misplaced closing parenthesis - move one of them before `"a"`

Comment: Uh, I don't think file objects have a `find` method?

Comment: @Aran-Fey they do not - but this is another mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a misplaced close-paren.

change:

```
var_1 = open("{}/Dekstop/Test_file.txt".format(environ["USERPROFILE"],"a"))
```

to:

```
var_1 = open("{}/Dekstop/Test_file.txt".format(environ["USERPROFILE"]), "a")
```

I'm going on a limb here and assume you wish to read the contents of `Test_file.txt` and if it contains the word "Test" you want the program to say "yay" and otherwise "noo".

To do this, first we must open the file in "read" mode. To do this, we use the `open()` function. Unfortunately, in your example code, you do `from os import *` which overrides the `open()` function with `os.open()`, which does something else entirely. So, let's get rid of those `import` statements.

Now that we have the proper `open()` function, we must call it with the name of the file we want to open and a short string indicating in which mode we want to open it. In your example, you have it set to `"a"`, which means to *append* to the file. Let's switch that to `"r"`, which means to read.

However, this only opens the file for reading, but doesn't actually read anything yet. Instead, it returns a `file` object. To read the contents of the file, we can use its `read()` method. This returns the contents of the file as a string. Now that we're done with reading from the file, we must be good citizens and close it, so that other programs may have access to the file. We can do that with the `close()` method of the `file` object.

Finally, we can check whether the word "Test" was in the contents using the `find()` method of the string, however, if the word is not found, `find()` returns `-1`. So, with all that in mind, try this version of your program:

```
import time

# Open the file for reading    
f = open("{}/Dekstop/Test_file.txt".format(environ["USERPROFILE"]), "r")

# Read the contents of the file
var_1 = f.read()

# Close the file so others may use it
f.close()

# The word to look for in the contents of the file
var_2 = "Test"

# Search the contents of the file
if var_1.find(var_2) != -1:
   print("yay")
else:
   print("noo")

# Pause for 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)
```

To wrap it all up, I leave you with a different version of your program that does exactly the same thing as the program above, but in fewer lines of code. It uses some cool Python functionality you may be interested in learning about:

```
import time

search_word = "Test"
with open("/u/45/vanvlm1/unix/playground/Test_file.txt") as f:
    if search_word in f.read():
        print("yay")
    else:
        print("noo")
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Now I get an other error... "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)"

Comment: That's because of the `from os import *` line. It masks the `open()` function you want with `os.open()`. I've edited my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Well thank you! Im still learning programing in general so im happy for every help I can get.

Comment: If this solves your problem, could you flag the answer as "accepted"? It gives me a small reputation bonus and signals to others that your question has been answered.

Comment: There are/were multiple things wrong with the code, such that the question should have been closed initially as needing more focus. The question has attracted a lot of attention due to the title; it ought to be the canonical for the problem about accidentally using `os.open`, but it doesn't work for that purpose now....